# Joomla extension install from URL error: Archive does not exist

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0, joomla-module

I am trying to install a package from URL into my local server and I am getting this error:

```
Error
Archive does not exist

Warning
JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla\tmp\install_53170ad5161e0
JFolder: :folder: Path is not a folder. Path: C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla\tmp\install_53170ad5161e0
JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla\tmp\install_53170ad5161e0
JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file
```

The tmp paths are correct and the remote file URL link is correct too. I've also tried by clearing the tmp folder but still does not help. The package installs correctly when the package file is uploaded.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 2):

**If you are using Linux**

You may need to fix the directory permissions. Check if there is any directory of which `CHMOD` is not `0777`. If there are folders which their `CHMOD` value is lower than `0777` set them to `0777`. After installation you have to change `chmod` back to `0755`

Answer (score 0):

Even though this post is quite old I hope that someone searching for a solution will stumble upon this question and answer:

I had the same problem when installing and updating Joomla on a Windows host, problems were related to directory permissions on various directories like "tmp", "modules" etc not being set. When I used the FTP client's `chmod` functionality the server responded with `504 Command not implemented for that parameter` (showing in green instead of red in my FTP protocol so I ) so permissions were never changed. I had to alter the security settings using the hoster's web interface, after that installing packages worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

only for this folder:

chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs

OR

project folder -

chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/project_name

Answer (score 0):

in **/var/www/you_site/httpdocs/configuration.php** change value:
$ftp_enable = '0';        set 0 from 1